# Does an algorithm exist to find the best logit model using a huge amount of variables?

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to run a (logit) model and to find the best combination of variables (namely the model with the smallest AIC or BIC criteria, and/or with the greatest number of significant variables). The problem is that I have 50 variables, thus being almost impossible to look for all combinations by hands.

I already look for answers on stackoverflow and on stackexchange without results.

I am relatively new on R so I already apologize if my question sounds bad, and I want to thanks the R community for their help

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `?step`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it exists! There are even two versions of it.

It is simply based on a stepwise (greedy) method adding (resp. removing) sequentially variables from the model from an empty model (resp. full model with all considered variables) trying to maximize AIC.

Its implementation can be found in the `MASS` package in R: `stepAIC` function (captionned "choose a model by AIC in a Stepwise Algorithm").

```
stepAIC(object, scope, scale = 0,
        direction = c("both", "backward", "forward"),
        trace = 1, keep = NULL, steps = 1000, use.start = FALSE,
        k = 2, ...)
```

`object` is the linear/logit model (`lm` or `glm` class).